# Xcode encountered Error : Internal logic error: Connection was invalidated error in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, ipados, xcode15

- While connecting to AnyConnect VPN(cisco secure client) then Xcode
  15 unable to find connected iPad(iPadOS 17.0.3)
  [image]

**

> Internal logic error: Connection was invalidated Domain:
> com.apple.CoreDevice.ControlChannelConnectionError Code: 1 User
> Info: { DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-09 07:50:50 +0000";
> "com.apple.dt.DVTCoreDevice.operationName" = enablePersonalizedDDI;
> } -- Transport error Domain:
> com.apple.CoreDevice.ControlChannelConnectionError Code: 0 -- The
> connection was interrupted. Domain: com.apple.Mercury.error Code:
> 1000 User Info: { XPCConnectionDescription =
> "<RemoteXPCPeerConnection 0x600003ac1b80> { <remote connection:
> 0x6000025c0f00> { type = rsd, state = not-connected, remote service
> name = com.apple.internal.dt.coredevice.untrusted.tunnelservice,
> server mode = 0, protocol version number = 1, protocol feature flags
> = 0x6, local service version = 0, remote service version = 2, traffic class = 0, (root, reply) helo received = (1, 1), next msg
> id
> = 11, first msg id = 3, send in progress = 0, preexisting socket = -1 }"; } -- System Information macOS Version 14.0 (Build
> 23A344) Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d) Timestamp:
> 2023-10-09T13:20:50+05:30 *

**

---

Comment: This issue exists since the update to macOS 14, it worked fine before.

Comment: Xcode 15 - macOS 14 - iOS 17.0.3: After connecting to the VPN, unable to see the physical device in Xcode.

Comment: Same problem after upgrading my iphone iOS v17 & later

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your Mac and the targeted device.